# Questionable audit question

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Today I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16039610) audit.
From the general layout and remarks on this page, in general twice the message

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

it is unclear to me what was exactly identified as possible spam. Was it the question, the answer or both?
I found the answer to be not helpful so I recommended deletion but I did not found it to be spam.
The answerer does not seem to have any affiliate with google that it failed to disclose and the tool he proposed seems helpful.

So my question(s)

What exactly was identified as spam?
Why would this answer be identified as spam (if my understanding that the system flagged it as such is right)?

Comment: The answer was originally flagged as spam (by users) and deleted.

Comment: Is it possible to get a screenshot for the lowly <10k users? :)

Comment: @Seth [<10k screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy6LC.png)

Comment: Uhh... Yeah, that isn't spam as far as I can see. Thanks for the screenshot @Floern :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it is unclear to me what was exactly identified as possible spam. Was it the question, the answer or both?

It will be the post that you are reviewing that was identified as spam. As far as I know the system doesn't look at the question (in the case of answers) or answers in the case of a question). So in this case it's just the answer.

In this case the user had provided two answers in close succession, both with the same link and little else. I can understand why both answers had been flagged by several users a spam. There was no indication in either answer that this is an official Google project so I can also understand people's reluctance to visit the link to check whether it's actually spam or not.

In this case if the link really isn't spam I can clear the spam flags which will remove the answer from being a possible audit - it will also undelete the answers.

However, if the answers start attracting flags again they're likely to get deleted again. If the answers were edited to include more information (not least the fact that this is a Google site) then that would help.

Comment: Can't we just clear the spam flags and then delete them manually as they are link only - NAA?

Comment: @NathanOliver I've cleared the spam flags, but if you think that they are NAA then you can either edit them to make them answers (which, from Seth's answer and other comments, they could well be), down-vote (though the user has no rep to lose) or flag them. As I said, if I see that they're attracting flags I'll probably delete, but not until then.

Comment: Sounds fair.  I went ahead and at least made it a little easier to read and make it clearer that the link is not a spam link.  The answer are duplicates so we might want to close the questions as dupes.  I'll leave that to others to decide though.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** Bad audit is bad. It's not spam and shouldn't have been nuked.

---

The warning `Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully` is shown when the question/answer that's currently being reviewed has been flagged as spam by one or more user(s). It is shown regardless of whether the review is an audit or not afaik.

---

Regarding the answer: **That is not spam**. The link leads to an **official google site** that offers the option of testing your website, and - IMHO - that is anything but spam, it isn't even NAA or VLQ as it does attempt to answer the question by pointing towards possible errors as well as linking to a way of further analyzing the problem, yet can still exist as answer without the link.

---

Regarding the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348810/5529417) by [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf): I can perfectly understand users being unwilling to click on unknown links, whether it's because they are at work, or don't want to expose themselves to malware etc., all cool. **But I personally expect those users to have the sense to not flag those questions or answers as spam.**

I mean, come on, if there's no indication of the post being a spam post, hop into a chat room (i.e. the SOCVR) and ask for a quick check. This takes a minute, if even. Or just google the link, and then check if

- the link is on the first google page (*if not, that's fishy*)
- the information text displayed on the result-page gives any indication about the site
- definitely-not-fishy-websites, i.e. G+, facebook etc.

I really hope that I am not the only one that expects at least that amount of effort of users before they're spam-flagging. I really do.

---

Here's what happens if you follow the steps above:

Googling `thinkwithgoogle` yields this as first result (*german language*): [image: Google result for "thinkwithgoogle"]

What you can (and can not) see, is:

- first link is that page, alongside its sub-pages => Looks anything but fishy
- second link is a twitter profile
- fifth link is a facebook profile with ~25k likes
- sixth link is a google+ profile with ~3m followers
- seventh link is a linkedin-profile

You can tell me whatever you want, but how does one get to the conclusion that nuking those answers without even checking the content of the link is anything but **blatant abuse of power?**

There are 4 links on the first google result page, all linking to official, verified and well-known social networks (facebook, twitter, google+, linkedin), two of which you don't even have to click to know anything about the follower count etc., as it's openly displayed.

How can one be so abstrusely lazy? It's mind-boggling.

Comment: Both of the user's answers (which were little more than links) were flagged by more than one person as spam.

Comment: @ChrisF I sadly cannot see the other answer of the user. Was that one spam, or was it also just linking to an official project of google?

Comment: It was the same link. Neither answer had any indication **in the answer** that the link was an official Google project.

Comment: @ChrisF Sorry, but if users are actually too lazy to at the very least google the links and check if the information text in the search results gives any indication about the site... Those users probably shouldn't flag anything anymore :) No offense, just saying, that little bit of effort should be doable.